# I want to generate tableview form with JSON data

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, ipad

I have a JSON data in my local file, I want to replicate same in my form.

JSON data tell us info like, which field is required, which is dropdown, placeholder and more info.

Almost I achieved my goal, but only the thing is keyboard taking double taps to show when I am switching the text fields.

I was stuck on this issue. Can anyone help me?

I cant explain the issue with the small code, that's why adding complete source code, so please excuse.

**here I am adding my source code link,**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/12vhrz6CgDSuma6ViYOsGkCIb9SE6fSbR/view

Comment: Please do't share the whole code... only show the code where you face issue.. like if issue with keyboard then show your TextField Delegate methods which you wrote...

Comment: After click on the text box tableview reload then reset all thats..

Comment: @ LeNI that's the issue. how can make it active?

Comment: Can you explain the issue in detail?

Comment: Do you need to click on textfield twice for keyboard to show. Is this the issue @Swathi?

Comment: Your problem could not exactly express in your question, thats the main reson for get some down votes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using :

```
func updateModel(text: String, indexPath: IndexPath) {

    var item        = self.viewModel.get(at: indexPath)
    item.value      = text
    item.indexPath  = indexPath
    self.viewModel.formModel[indexPath.section].items![indexPath.row] = item
    self.tableForm?.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
}
```

Also, avoid retain cycle using weak self :

```
    self.viewModel.fetchFormData(fileName: "fields") { [weak self] (data, error) in

        if (error?.isEmpty)! {
            self?.tableForm?.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Otherwise ViewController & ViewModelForm will be kept in memory forever

Comment: it doesnt fix the issue

Comment: Hm, I tried actually. It avoid the reloadData so the select textfield stays on screen …

Comment: it reloads the textfield that were first entered

Comment: It reloads the previous textfield, not the current one. This method is called in `textFieldDidEndEditing`

Comment: we should fix that also right

Comment: People are so irritated …

Comment: @GaétanZ, I am facing some weird issue after changes. I'm filling the form from last to first and skipping without filling' like playing around use-cases it is behaving weirdly. Sections header changing, text field value interchanging.

Comment: Remove the indexpath from your `FormItem`. `let indexPath = (self.superview as! UITableView).indexPathForRow(at: textFieldPosition)` is bad. Pass your tableViewCell instance in the method of your delegate instead and use `tableView.indexPathForCell` in the controller to retrieve the corresponding indexPath. Also, put all the configuration code of your cells in `configure(cell:,item)` and remove the `formItem?.indexPath == indexPath && (formItem?.value?.isEmpty)!` condition.

Answer (score 0):

In updateModel function you need to replace

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

with

```
self.tableForm?.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
```

So the basic rule says if you only wish to reload a single row in table view use reloadRows instead of reloading the complete table view.

Comment: Thats also maintain in the previous answer and its works fine

Comment: If I do that not working. I already tried. If I'm interchanging between sections it is giving wrong output. You can see that filling and skipping text field in between section, the output is unexpected.

Comment: You are not maintaining the UI state